# (Azure Data Factory Pipeline) For each Notebook in a specific folder

Tags: jupyter-notebook, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

How can I create a ForEach activity that:

1. Get the list of all Notebooks existing in a specific folder workspace in Databricks.
2. Execute each Notebook

Because currently, I'm doing it by adding a Notebook activity for each Notebook, and connecting them one after another.
But this kind of working is not efficient, because when a new Notebook is created in Databricks, I must remember to update my Pipeline execution in Azure Synapse Data Factory.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/workspace#example-4) to get the Notebooks list in a cluster.
First, I tried to get the list using web activity but not able to do it. That's why I have used Databricks notebook(`start_notebook`) to get the list of notebooks and then filtered required notebooks.

**`start_notebook` code:**

```
import requests
import json

my_json = {"path": "/Users/< yours@mail.com >/Folder/"}    

auth = {"Authorization": "Bearer <Access token>"}

response = requests.get('https://adb-1234567890123456.7.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/workspace/list', json = my_json, headers=auth).json()
dbutils.notebook.exit(response)
```

Then In ADF Notebook activity output you can get the list of notebook as JSON array like below.

[image]

Now use filter activity to filter the `start_notebook` from the above array.

I have used a parameter for the name.

[image]

**Filter activity:**

[image]

**Items:** `@activity('Notebook1').output.runOutput.objects`
**Condition:**`@not(equals(last(split(string(item().path),'/')), pipeline().parameters.start))`

**Filter output array:**

[image]

Give this output array to a ForEach as `@activity("Filter1").output.Value` and inside forEach use Notebook activity(give `@item().path` for Notebook path).

[image]